# Why does tha last row of this listview always act strange?

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to display a `ListView` where each row represents the answer to a question. When the user presses the button *CHECK* I want the rows of the `ListView` to **change color according to the result** (if the answer was wrong, correct, not selected and so on...).

In my `onCreateView()` I'm creating the following `CursorAdapter`:

```
Cursor crs = db.queryQuestionAnswers(questionID); // a cursor with all answers relative to the question
adapter = new CursorAdapter(getActivity(), crs, 0) {
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        return ((LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
                .inflate(R.layout.listfragment_test_row, listview, false); // Row of the listview
    }

    // Instance items of each row
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor crs) {
        Answer answer = test.getQuestion(current_question).getAnswer(crs.getPosition());
        TextView answerTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ans_test_button);
        answerTv.setText(answer.getText());
        view.setOnClickListener(new AnswerOnClickListener(answer));
        if (show_solution) { // User has clicked "CHECK"
            displayResult(view, answer); // Color answers according to selection and correctness
        } else
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); // The question has just been displayed
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        Cursor cursorAdapter = adapter.getCursor();
        cursorAdapter.moveToPosition(position);
        return cursorAdapter.getLong(cursorAdapter.getColumnIndex(DatabaseStrings.FIELD_ID));
    }
};
```

Whenever the user presses the *CHECK* button so (bringing `show_solution` to `true`), the app should check the following fields and **act on the relative view accordingly**:

```
private void displayResult(View view, Answer answer) {
    view.setEnabled(false);
    if (answer.isSolution() && answer.isChoice()) // User selected a correct answer
        view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorLightGreen));
    else if (answer.isChoice()) // User selected a wrong answer
        view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorMediumRed));
    else if (answer.isSolution()) // User didn't select a solution
        view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorLightBlue));
    else { // Answer was nor selected nor solution
        // [...] Hide view with an animation [..]
        }
    }
}
```

But in **all cases the last answer gets colored** (apparently with a random color) **and then vanishes** (as it was nor selected nor solution).

It looks like for **only the last row** the program enters in all `if` statements.

The **only case** when it works as it was supposed to, is **when the user selects all answers**: correct ones are colored green and wrong one red... while no answer vanishes. Not even the last one.

I managed to fix the problem relative to the color adding the following line inside the last `else` statement.

```
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

But the last line keep vanishing. What's wrong?

**EDIT:**
Here's the `AnswerOnClickListener` implementation:

```
// Listener for answer selection
public class AnswerOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    Answer answer;

    private AnswerOnClickListener(Answer answer) { this.answer = answer; }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        answer.changeChoice();
        if (answer.isChoice()) { // Answer has been selected by the user
            v.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.colorLightYellow));
        } else { // Answer has been deselected by the user
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's your `AnswerOnClickListener`?

Comment: @ReazMurshed you are right: I'm adding it to the OP, wait a minute! :)

Comment: What is the current status, only the last item is not working?

Comment: @Hahn exactly! Only the last one

Comment: This line may be the cuplrit: // [...] Hide view with an animation [..]...put some logs there and see if the last item is getting removed here